# capture Ansible WARNING messages to a variable

Tags: search, ansible, warnings, ansible-facts

I have the below playbook:

```
- name: Play 1.5 - Check Python on each target
  hosts: "{{ location }}"
  user: "{{ USER }}"
  ignore_unreachable: yes
  ignore_errors: yes
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

   - setup:
       gather_subset:
         - network
     register: setupdata

   - debug:
       msg: "SETUP: {{ setupdata }}"
```

For a few inventory hosts I get the below `WARNING` message when i print `setupdata` variable as below:

Output:

```
ok: [10.9.10.16] => {
    "msg": "SETUP: {'warnings': [u\"No python interpreters found for host 10.9.10.16 (tried ['/usr/bin/python', 'python3.7', 'python3.6', 'python3.5', 'python2.7', 'python2.6', '/usr/libexec/platform-python', '/usr/bin/python3', 'python'])\"], 'module_stderr': u'This system is for the use of authorized users only. Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their activities on this system monitored and recorded by system personnel. In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities of authorized users may also be monitored. Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring and is advised that if such such monitoring reveals possible evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the evidence of such monitoring to the law enforcement officials\\n/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python:  not found\\n', 'changed': False, 'module_stdout': u'', 'failed': True, 'rc': 127, 'msg': u'MODULE FAILURE\\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error', 'ansible_facts': {u'discovered_interpreter_python': u'/usr/bin/python'}}"
}
```

Is it possible to search for a string `No python interpreters found for host` in the output above ?

I tried the below but it fails to search:

```
   - debug:
       msg: "No Python Found on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
     when: setupdata | join('') | regex_search('No python interpreters found for host')
```

Can you please suggest how can I capture the `WARNING` message and search for a string in the WARNING?

Comment: Did you notice that `setupdata` has a `warnings` that is `list[str]`? I would guess you'd want `when: setupdata.warnings is search("No python interpreters")` instead of trying to `join` on a `dict`

Comment: @mdaniel works !! I also got this to work: `setupdata | to_json | regex_search('No python interpreters found for host'). Can you post as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that `setupdata` has a key in it named `warnings` that is `list[str]` and is a much better candidate for the actual `when`. You can test members of that list by changing the `when:` to use the [`search` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings), which *pedantically speaking* should be applied using the `contains` test, but just feeding the list into `search` seems to do what I expected and is easier to read

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "No Python Found on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when: setupdata.warnings is search('No python interpreters')
```